# Cannot compile 5.1.1 in Win10 x64

Tags: omnet++

When I try to compile omnet++, I get this error:

```
$/c/opt/omnetpp-5.1.1$ ./configure
configure: loading site script /mingw64/etc/config.site
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh src/utils/config.sub
```

v5.1 gives the same error. v5.0 works fine. I suspect this is because of the switch to x64.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to mactype. Fixed: https://github.com/msys2/msys2/issues/25